# Is there a simple way to get suggestions for a line of JS code?

Tags: javascript, code-editor

If I have a string of *valid* JS code, for example `"'foobar'.charCodeAt(0)"`, I can evaluate it — it is obviously simple. 
 `eval()` (or `new Function()`) in JS code or `node -e` (or `d8 -e`) from CLI solves this task.

But I have a need to get a potential suggestions for an *incomplete* line of JS code. 
 For example, if I have a string `"'foobar'.cha"` I want something like an array `['charAt', 'charCodeAt, 'matchAll']` (or `["'foobar'.charAt", "'foobar'.charCodeAt", "'foobar'.matchAll"]`).

Is there a reliable and preferably out-of-box solution for it? It's not a big deal for me and I do not want to spent too much time on it.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for auto-complete suggestions in your editor?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara No. I want a code solution for the described task. Sort of JavaScript (not necessary exactly JS) program (a code snippet) which get a string and return string with solutions.

Comment: Many popular code editors already do this. If you're attempting to create an autocomplete feature as a learning project, have fun, but don't waste time re-inventing the wheel if you just want to use the feature to increase your productivity. MS Code is pretty great imo: https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: @Emma Do you mean a linter? OP mentions " I have a need to get a potential suggestions". I don't think that is the case. This is what auto-complete plugins do, not linters.

Comment: @undefined You may suppose I write my own tiny-tiny JS editor. %)

Comment: @TomO. Thank you, I already use VS Code. :) It's not about it.

Comment: @shau-kote That sounds interesting! Good luck with that. You must be very young or ambitious :)

Comment: @Emma No, I do not need a linting or validation, only suggestions. It is sufficiently to get sort of "no suggestions" message if line with code is invalid or unclear.

Comment: @undefined Thank you. I am not so young but try to remain ambitious. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be more complex than this, but once you are able to properly parse the code, you can get an array of prototype functions by doing something like: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String.prototype)` - or whatever prototype you need, just using `String` in this example.

```js
function getFuncs(type) {
  if (type === 'string') {
    var funcs = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String.prototype).reduce((accum, el) => {
      accum.push(el);
      return accum;
    }, []);
    //console.log(funcs);
    return funcs;
  }
  console.log(`${type} not implemented yet..`);
  return;
}

var divEl = document.querySelector('#divEl');
document.querySelector('#inputEl').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  divEl.innerHTML = '<ul>';
  var funcs = getFuncs(typeof e.target.value);
  var filtered = funcs.filter(fnName => {
    return fnName.toLowerCase().indexOf(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  });
  if (e.target.value.trim() != '') {
    filtered.forEach(fnName => divEl.innerHTML += `<li>${fnName}</li>`);
  }

  divEl.innerHTML += '</ul>';
});
```

```html
"foobar.<input id="inputEl" type="text" />"
<br />
<div id="divEl"></div>
```

Comment: Yep, you have managed to write a minimum viable demo for an idea which was spinning in my head but was obscure. But this approach doesn't look simple or out-of-box. Firstly it requires a full-featured JS parser (okay, I think there is some libraries for it). Secondly even an almighty code parser will not be possible fo determine type of the complete part of code — it may require partial execution for cases like `"(1 + 1).to"` or even `"(() => 'foobar')().cha"` (the latter is slightly exorbitant though).

Comment: I think if you really wanted it could be achieved if you use a good parser such as Esprima: http://esprima.org/. The parser will create a syntax tree containing `Node`s. Each `Node` will contain metadata including `type` which you could probably use in your program.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Hope I can use it (it does not look like very simply solution).